# iOS, how to cache file on Apple Watch

Tags: ios, swift, apple-watch

I generate image on phone and send it to apple watch.

```
func session(_ session: WCSession, didReceive file: WCSessionFile) {
    let img = UIImage(contentsOfFile: file.fileURL.path)
    self.image.setImage(img)
}
```

This image I need regenerate rarely. How can I cache it on apple watch? Is `NSFileManager` available on watch?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, NSFileManager is available. For the most part a WatchKit app works just like an iOS one.